# Dereferencing Pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, struct

I've been at this for a couple hours and can't figure out this probably stupid mistake. Here are the errors:

```
crawler.c:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

crawler.c:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

crawler.c:10: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
```

The code is:

```
//--------------------------Header File----------------------------------//
#ifndef CRAWLER_H 
#define CRAWLER_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "indexPage.h"
struct pointersWordControl{
    queryHelper **queryArray;
    char** URLs;
};
typedef struct pointersWordControl queryHelperExt;
queryHelperExt  *crawler(const char* FILE_NAME, const int MAX_N);
#endif  

//---------------------------------Crawler.c-------------------------------//
queryHelperExt *crawler(const char* FILE_NAME, const int Max_N)
{

    queryHelper **structArray = malloc(sizeof(struct wordControl*)*50); 
    char** urlString;
    urlString= missionControl(FILE_NAME, Max_N, structArray);
    struct queryHelperExt *queryPass=malloc(sizeof(struct pointersWordControl)*1);
    queryPass->queryArray=structArray;
    queryPass->URLs=urlString; 
    return queryPass;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
struct queryHelperExt *queryPass=malloc(sizeof(struct pointersWordControl)*1);
```

to

```
queryHelperExt *queryPass=malloc(sizeof(struct pointersWordControl)*1);
```

There is no `struct queryHelperExt` - the identifier `queryHelperExt` is a typedef for `struct pointersWordControl` and doesn't need the `struct` keywork.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're declaring `queryPass` to be of type `struct queryHelperExt` which is different from the intended type of `queryHelperExt`.  In C, adding the `struct` keyword makes it a different type (unlike C++).